# Error: function crashed. Details: connect ECONNREFUSED /cloudsql/<instance Connection Name>>

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am not able to connect **Cloud Functions to Cloud SQL** database facing the issue like that

Code which I used to connect the database:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
exports.mysql = function handler(req, res) {
    var c = mysql.createConnection({
        socketPath: '/cloudsql/' + 'instance Connection Name',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'lns12345',
        database: 'Sample'
    });
    c.connect();
    c.query('SELECT * from user', req.body.user, function(e, results) {
        //made reply here
        if (results) {
            console.log('Database succeed')
        } else {
            console.log('new error created')
        }
        console.log('my E result is :', e)
        console.log('My results is :', results)
    });

};
```

Error what I received:

```
Error: function crashed. Details:
connect ECONNREFUSED /cloudsql/'instance Connection Name'
```

Detailed Log which I got in Cloud Functions:

```
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED /cloudsql/'instance connection Name' at
 Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11) at
 exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20) at
 PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1105:14)
 -------------------- at Protocol._enqueue (/user_code/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48) at
 Protocol.handshake
 (/user_code/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23) at
 Connection.connect
 (/user_code/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18) at handler
 (/user_code/index.js:20:4) at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:684:7 at
 /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:668:9 at _combinedTickCallback
 (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7) at process._tickDomainCallback
 (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Comment: At which javascript line your program is crashing ? If it is at c.connect(), it is not necessary to put the code after because it polluate your question.

Comment: What represent 'instance Connection Name' ? It is the real name used or a string used only for the question ?

Comment: Can you format the StackTrace so that your question would be easier to read for others ? You have formatted your source code, so I propose that you format the StackTrace using same technic :-)

Comment: I think that if you make all these changes, another "corrector" will accept your question !

Comment: > Actually when connecting with the Cloudsql with cloudfunctions by the socketpath it is not able to connect

Comment: > 'instance connection name' => cloud sql Connection name i.e which involve in that connection name "PROJECTID:REGION:instanceid"

Comment: I have been able to create a Cloud Function and connect to CloudSQL. Please try this code https://pastebin.com/DV316N2e and substitute `'projectname:us-central1:instancename'`, `'my-database-name'` and `my-table-name` with your own values. also take into account that this is a work in progress according to this Feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36388165

Answer (score 1):

Replace `'instance Connection Name'` placeholder with the actual connection name